# Parent and Child components in ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to build a parent component with several dumped sub-components.

I don't quite figure out how design my dump sub-components. Theorically, each sub-component has to receive all data using `@Input` fields. So:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[payment-list]',
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PaymentList  {
  @Input() payments$: Observable<ISource>;
```

What I'm trying to get using this input field is to list all payments are in payments. This is my `IStore`:

```
export interface IStore {
  user: IUser;
  plans: IPlanRedux;
  sources: ISourceRedux;
  errors: IError;
}

export interface ISource {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    customer: string;
}

export interface ISourceRedux {
    byId: { [key: string]: ISource };
    allIds: Array<string>;
}
```

Parent component builds an `Observable<ISource>` using this:

```
private sources$: Observable<ISource>;

constructor(private store$: Store<IStore>) {
    this.sources$ = this.store$
        .select(fromRoot.getSourceEntities);
}
```

So, into my `parent.template.html`:

```
<div payment-list></div>
```

1. Dumped component needs to receive necessary all information using `@Input` fields? So, how could I send the parent observable to the dumped component? Is it correct?
2. Could dumped components build its owned `Observables` and use them?
3. Is there any best-practice approach to deal with this issue using ngrx?

Comment: It's dumB (=not smart :) and I would keep observables or any logic out of them. Best handle filtering and stuff in parent (smart component) and let child (dumb component) deal with pure data and UI.

Answer (score 2):

Your sub-component dont need a stream for that it only need the ISource object to function.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[payment-list]',
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PaymentList  {
  @Input() payments: ISource;

private sources$: Observable<ISource>;
constructor(private store$: Store<IStore>) {
    this.sources$ = this.store$
        .select(fromRoot.getSourceEntities);
}

<payment-list payments="sources$ | async"></payment-list>
```

This approach makes your sub-component dumb in the way that it does not need to be aware of the store